# Error while Setting up Angular 2 environment on Windows 7/64 bit

Tags: angular

I was setting up the environment for angular 2 on my local machine running Windows 7 64 bit OS. I successfully installed the node JS v6.11.0 LTS on my machine but when I'm trying to install Angular cli using npm by this command-

> npm install -g @angular/cli

It throws following error-

> Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 6.11.0 (x64) and
>   npm.
>
> ```
> C:\Users\XYZ>npm install -g @angular/cli
> URIError: URI malformed
> at decodeURIComponent (native)
> at Url.parse (url.js:269:19)
> at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:75:5)
> at Object.validateUrl [as validate] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:164:13)
> at validate (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:213:24)
> at validate (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:179:11)
> at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:101:12
> at Array.map (native)
> at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:67:15
> at Array.forEach (native)
> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:39
>   throw new Error('npm.load() required')
>   ^
> Error: npm.load() required
> at Object.get (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:39:13)
> at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:60:40)
> at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:180:3)
> at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
> at process.emit (events.js:188:7)
> at processEmit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\node_modules\gauge\node_modules\signal-exit\index.js:146:32)
> at processEmit [as emit] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\node_modules\npmlog\node_modules\gauge\node_modules\signal-exit\index.js:146:32)
> at process._fatalException (bootstrap_node.js:296:26)     URIError: URI malformed
> at decodeURIComponent (native)
> at Url.parse (url.js:269:19)
> at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:75:5)
> at Object.validateUrl [as validate] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:164:13)
> at validate (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:213:24)
> at validate (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:179:11)
> at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:101:12
> at Array.map (native)
> at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:67:15
> at Array.forEach (native)
> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:39
>   throw new Error('npm.load() required')
>   ^
> Error: npm.load() required
> at Object.get (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:39:13)
> at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:60:40)
> at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:180:3)
> at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
> at process.emit (events.js:188:7)
> at processEmit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\node_modules\gauge\node_modules\signal-exit\index.js:146:32)
> at processEmit [as emit] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\node_modules\npmlog\node_modules\gauge\node_modules\signal-exit\index.js:146:32)
> at process._fatalException (bootstrap_node.js:296:26)
> C:\Users\XYZ>
> ```

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: which version of `npm` you are using?

Comment: I'm using NPM version- 3.10.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by changing the PROXY and HTTPS-PROXY URLs contained in the .NPMRC file.